# How to keep ice cream frozen when defrosting freezer?

Tags: home, kitchen

I have frozen ice cream in my freezer, but I need to defrost the freezer now, so how do I keep the ice cream frozen during that time? How can I prevent it from melting and spilling out from the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The day before you want to defrost, freeze a few trays of ice cubes. Anything else that's frozen works too. The idea is to get a large mass of cold material in the box, that way it takes longer to warm up.
2. On the day, place the ice cream in a box with the ice cubes. Use an insulated cooler if you have one, or wrap a few layers of bubble wrap (or other insulating material) around an ordinary plastic or cardboard box.
3. Defrost the freezer quickly: pour warm water on the ice to thaw it. This helps you finish the defrosting and cleaning before your ice cream thaws.

Comment: Thanks. Actually you give me really nice idea. I'm thinking if wrap ice cream box with polythene paper tightly to not to split even if will melt and put it in plastic container with filling water and then freeze it so It'll melt slowly and even without worry for whether ice cream would melt or not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Blankets/duvets/sleeping bags around whatever box you keep your icecream in will help to keep it cool.

Comment: I have a load of cold-pads - used for transporting medication. we also have similar things, cool-blocks, for camping. Freeze a load of these and pack your ice-cream with them in blankets, cardboard, bubble pack - whatever you've got handy. You could also use a big sack of frozen peas in the same way.

Comment: @Hobbes Well as I said I've got an idea. I just wrapped box in polythene paper with help of tape and then defrost. I seem it's work very nice.

Comment: @Swapnil:  I've seen melted and re-frozen ice cream before and it wasn't pretty.  The re-frozen ice-cream was at least twice the density of the original ice cream.  Instead of being "fluffy", it was a hard, gooey mess.

Comment: Ohh, So I must keep frozen then I would try what I said in my comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Defrost the refrigerator when it is below freezing outside.  Keep the ice cream outside in the shade during this time.

Hopefully you live in a climate where sub-zero temperatures are common.

Comment: No It's hot summer in here.

Comment: This is how I do it. In winter it gets under -10 C here.

Answer (score 4):

Ask your neighbors if they have some spare room in their freezer... 
The simplest answer.. i'm sure!

Comment: I done with wrapping polythene paper around box tightly and that's why I don't need to worry if it'd melt and spilling out.

Answer (score 3):

Put the ice cream in a small insulated cooler with a small block of dry ice (available at many supermarkets, near the regular ice).  That will keep the ice cream solid while the freezer defrosts.

Comment: I like this dry ice idea even better than the accepted answer (which involves _wet_ ice cubes)! upvote

Comment: Dry-ice is not available everywhere, so while this method is good where it is easy to find, it will not work elsewhere.